# Tex Live 2015, KOMA-script pagesize=automedia yields Undefined Control Sequence

Tags: texlive, koma-script

The following LaTeX file compiles fine on Tex Live 2014, but fails on Tex Live 2015:

```
\documentclass[pagesize=automedia]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Compilation with Tex Live 2015 (either `pdflatex` or `lualatex`) gives:

```
$ /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex mini
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mini.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty) (./mini.aux
)
! Undefined control sequence.
\@tempc ...ia}\if@atdocument \set@pdftextpagesize 
                                                  \set@vtexpagesize \set@dvi...
l.3 \begin{document}

? 
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
[2] (./mini.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on mini.pdf (2 pages, 22135 bytes).
Transcript written on mini.log.
```

The resulting PDF looks fine, although I did not estimate if the size of the textarea is correct.

Why is this happening and how can I circumvent this problem?

Comment: That's a typo in typearea.sty, it uses ` \set@pdftextpagesize` instead of ` \set@pdftexpagesize`. Make a bug report. I doubt that you need the option. Or due you have vtex?

Comment: I probably don't need the option, I just copied over my standard set of options from before.  How would I make a bug report — just e-mailing the maintainers?

Comment: Yes, the mail address is in the docu on page 25, or sent a message at http://www.komascript.de/

Comment: Send Markus a mail.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have.  Apparently, it had already been reported, see [answer below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266701/8141).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug that is reported in the [KOMA-script 3.18 release notes](http://www.komascript.de/release3.18) on the KOMA-script website, It can be found via the (obvious?) path:

[*Startseite*](http://www.komascript.de/) › [*Dokumentation*](http://www.komascript.de/book) > [*KOMA-Script Dokumentations-Buch*](http://www.komascript.de/scrdoc) › [*Was ich schon immer fragen wollte ...*](http://www.komascript.de/faq) › [*Fragen zur KOMA-Script-Anleitung und der KOMA-Script Verteilung*](http://www.komascript.de/faqnichtlatex) › [*Welches ist die aktuelle KOMA-Script-Release und wo finde ich sie?*](http://www.komascript.de/release) > [*Bekannte Probleme und Änderungen in KOMA-Script 3.18*](http://www.komascript.de/release3.18):

> **typearea**
>
> Bei Verwendung von Option `pagesize=automedia` kann u. U. eine Fehlermeldung wegen nicht definiertem `\set@pdftextpagesize` auftreten.
>   Workaround: `\makeatletter\def\set@pdftextpagesize{\set@pdftexpagesize}\makeatother` in der Dokumentpräambel einfügen. Dieser Workaround stört auch nicht, wenn der Fehler in der nächsten Release behoben sein wird.
>   Hinweis: Der Fehler ist in der [aktuellen Bugfix-Release](http://www.komascript.de/current) bereits behoben.

Translation in English by me:

> **typearea**
>
> When using the option `pagesize=automedia`, under circumstances an error message due to an undefined `\set@pdftextpagesize` can occur.  Workaround: add `\makeatletter\def\set@pdftextpagesize{\set@pdftexpagesize}\makeatother` to the document preamble.  This workaround is not harmful when the bug will be fixed in the next release.  Hint: the bug is already fixed in the [current bugfix-release](http://www.komascript.de/current).